# Crontab is not running in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron, database, shell-scripting

I want to do database back. I have created two files one is '.sh' and another one is '.py' file. both have execution permission.

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 acespritech-bhaviraj acespritech-bhaviraj 152 Aug  8 14:26 google_drive_v8_backup.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 acespritech-bhaviraj acespritech-bhaviraj 334 Aug  8 14:26 google_drive_v8_db_backup.py
```

I have the following code into '.sh' file:

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
#database backup code Dump DBs
echo "123456"|sudo -S /bin/bash -c "sudo python google_drive_v8_db_backup.py"
#database backup code ends
```

and into '.py' file I have following code:

```python
import os
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
db_file_name = 'google_drive_v8'+'_'+datetime.strftime(datetime.today(), '%d_%m_%y_%H_%M_%S'+'.sql') 
os.system("echo 123456|sudo su acespritech-bhaviraj /bin/bash -c 'pg_dump -E UTF-8 -p 5432 -F p -b -f  '"+db_file_name+"' google_drive_v8' acespritech-bhaviraj")
```

I have run this two files manually I got database backup done, but when I add this '.sh' file into crontab like this  below:

```
10 * * * * /bin/bash /home/acespritech-bhaviraj/backup/google_drive_v8_backup.sh
```

it is not running.

can you please help we what should I do?

Comment: That's a lot of nested sudos. And as far as I can tell they are completely unnecessary.

Comment: Also, starting a bash to then start Python is unnecessary. And read the part about the restricted cron environment in the question I linked.